# how to get only first name in facebook app

Tags: php, facebook

I need to retrieve only first name in facebook app(php sdk).The Below Code Retrieves full name.

```
$name = $friend['name'];
```

Comment: `list($name,) = explode(" ", $friend['name'], 2);`

Comment: i get a error that..imagettftext() expects parameter 8 to be string

Comment: Provide the relevant code dealing with the error.

Answer (score 7):

You have a look at `graph api` for that: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

https://graph.facebook.com/4/ gives you:

```
{
   "id": "4",
   "name": "Mark Zuckerberg",
   "first_name": "Mark",
   "last_name": "Zuckerberg",
   "link": "https://www.facebook.com/zuck",
   "username": "zuck",
   "gender": "male",
   "locale": "en_US"
}
```

For your case try:

```
$name = $friend['first_name'];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can split a string into an array using `explode()` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php), then use the first index in that array.

E.g.

`$name = explode(' ', 'Justin Biaber');`

which would give

`$name[0] = 'Justin'`, `$name[1] = 'Biaber'`